# A simple formula interpreter

Tags: rust

To understand Rust, I am trying to implement a little formula interpreter.
An expression can only be an integer, a sum, a variable (`Term`) or an assignment (`Set`). We can then evaluate an expression. Since symbols with no associated values can appear in an expression, its evaluation yields another expression (and not necessarily an integer).

The values of the variables (if there are any) can be found in a hash table.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Expr {
    Integer(i32),
    Term(String),
    Plus(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
    Set(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
}

impl Expr {
    fn evaluate(&self, env: &mut HashMap<String, Expr>) -> Expr {
        match *self {
            Expr::Plus(ref a, ref b) => {
                let a_ev = Rc::new(a.evaluate(env));
                let b_ev = Rc::new(b.evaluate(env));
                match (*a_ev, *b_ev) {
                    (Expr::Integer(x), Expr::Integer(y)) => Expr::Integer(x + y),
                    _ => Expr::Plus(a_ev, b_ev),
                }
            }
            Expr::Term(ref a) => *env.get(&a).unwrap(),
            Expr::Set(ref a, ref b) => {
                let b_ev = Rc::new(b.evaluate(env));
                match **a {
                    Expr::Term(x) => {
                        let x_value = env.get_mut(&x).unwrap();
                        *x_value = *b_ev;
                        *b_ev
                    }
                    otherwise => {
                        let a_ev = Rc::new(a.evaluate(env));
                        Expr::Set(a_ev, b_ev)
                    }
                }
            }
            otherwise => otherwise,
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does not compile. Each `match` seems to borrow a variable. Moreover, I think we should not use the `String` type, but I can't understand why.

The compilation error:

> ```
> error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::borrow::Borrow<&std::string::String>` is not satisfied
>   --> src/main.rs:22:39
>    |
> 22 |             Expr::Term(ref a) => *env.get(&a).unwrap(),
>    |                                       ^^^ the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<&std::string::String>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
>    |
>    = help: the following implementations were found:
>              <std::string::String as std::borrow::Borrow<str>>
> ```

Comment: I would recommend posting questions like "Is this code idiomatic?" to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Adrian I agree, but Code Review requires *working code*, which this doesn't seem to be, yet.

Comment: By the way, why use `Rc`? Normally expressions form tree, so the unique owner of an `Expr` is the outer `Expr` that contains it. I don't think it would solve any of your compilation errors, but it's certainly not idiomatic to use `Rc` needlessly. `String`, however, is just fine when a string slice is not appropriate or too much pain.

Comment: @delnan: "Normally expressions form tree". Normally expressions for a DAG due to sharing of subexpressions. In that case there is no unique owner at compile time in the general case so you need to resort to a more general form of memory management. In the absence of a tracing GC, reference counting is the next most logical option although it is slower and leaks cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is somewhat subjective, but here are some problems I see:

---

```
let a_ev = Rc::new(a.evaluate(env));
let b_ev = Rc::new(b.evaluate(env));
match (*a_ev, *b_ev) {
    (Expr::Integer(x), Expr::Integer(y)) => Expr::Integer(x+y),
    _ => Expr::Plus(a_ev,b_ev)
}
```

Here, you can't dereference `a_ev` and `b_ev` because `*a_ev` is owned by the `Rc` container holding it. You can fix this error by waiting until you actually need the values to be put in `Rc` containers to create them:

```
match (a.evaluate(env), b.evaluate(env)) {
    (Expr::Integer(x), Expr::Integer(y)) => Expr::Integer(x + y),
    (a_ev, b_ev) => Expr::Plus(Rc::new(a_ev), Rc::new(b_ev))
}
```

---

```
Expr::Term(ref a) => *env.get(&a).unwrap()
```

Here, the variable `a` has type `&String`, and so writing `&a` makes no sense -- it would be like a reference to a reference. That can be fixed by changing `&a` to `a`. Also, `env.get(a).unwrap()` is a reference to a `Expr` that is owned by the `HashMap`, so you can't dereference/move it. One solution to this problem would be to use a `HashMap<String, Rc<Expr>>` instead of a `HashMap<String, Expr>`. Another would be to simply clone the value:

```
Expr::Term(ref a) => env.get(a).unwrap().clone(),
```

In order to be able to clone the value, you must use a "derive" compiler directive to say that `Expr` implements that trait:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
enum Expr {   // ...
```

---

```
let b_ev = Rc::new(b.evaluate(env));
match **a {
    Expr::Term(x) => {
        let x_value = env.get_mut(&x).unwrap();
         *x_value = *b_ev;
         *b_ev
    },
    // ...
```

Here, you move `*b_ev` into the `HashMap` and then try to dereference/move it again by returning it. Also, like above, you have an extra `&`. Both of these issues can be solved in the same way as above:

```
let b_ev = b.evaluate(env);
match **a {
    Expr::Term(ref x) => {
        let x_value = env.get_mut(x).unwrap();
        *x_value = b_ev.clone();
        b_ev
    },
    // ...
```

---

```
otherwise => { let a_ev = Rc::new(a.evaluate(env)); // ...
```

Here, you are moving `**a` into `otherwise` while it is still owned by an `Rc` container. Since you don't use `otherwise`, the problem is easily fixed by replacing it with `_`:

```
_ => { // ...
```

---

```
otherwise => otherwise
```

You can't take a value that is owned by something else (`*self` is owned by something else) and return it by value. You can, however, clone it:

```
_ => self.clone()
```

---

Overall, the problem with your code is that it tries to duplicate data in a few places. As I said above, there are two ways of fixing it that I can think of: using `Rc<Expr>` *everywhere* instead of `Expr`, or using `clone`. Here is a fixed version of your code that compiles and uses `clone`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum Expr {
    Integer(i32),
    Term(String),
    Plus(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
    Set(Rc<Expr>, Rc<Expr>),
}

impl Expr {
    fn evaluate(&self, env: &mut HashMap<String, Expr>) -> Expr {
        match *self {
            Expr::Plus(ref a, ref b) => {
                match (a.evaluate(env), b.evaluate(env)) {
                    (Expr::Integer(x), Expr::Integer(y)) => Expr::Integer(x + y),
                    (a_ev, b_ev) => Expr::Plus(Rc::new(a_ev), Rc::new(b_ev))
                }
            },
            Expr::Term(ref a) => env.get(a).unwrap().clone(),
            Expr::Set(ref a, ref b) => {
                let b_ev = b.evaluate(env);
                match **a {
                    Expr::Term(ref x) => {
                        let x_value = env.get_mut(x).unwrap();
                        *x_value = b_ev.clone();
                        b_ev
                    },
                    _ => {
                        let a_ev = a.evaluate(env);
                        Expr::Set(Rc::new(a_ev), Rc::new(b_ev))
                    }
                }
            }
            _ => self.clone()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e = Expr::Plus(Rc::new(Expr::Integer(9)), Rc::new(Expr::Integer(34)));
    let mut env = HashMap::new();

    println!("{:?}", e.evaluate(&mut env));
}
```

[[playpen](http://is.gd/YlFDmy)]

Comment: thank you for the answer, but there is something I don't understand about return values. I thought this was an antipattern for a function in Rust to return a pointer.

Comment: It is not necessarily a bad idea to return a pointer/reference from a function. Generally, in Rust, you would return a pointer/reference in the same situations that you would return one in C/C++. For example, there are functions which return references in your code: `env.get(a).unwrap()` returns a `&Expr`.

Comment: thanks ! I still have trouble to get the code right if the return value is a `Rc` pointer. I would like to replace the line `match (a.evaluate(env), b.evaluate(env))` with `match (*a.evaluate(env), *b.evaluate(env))` but those values are owned by the `Rc` container and cannot be moved.

Comment: The expression `*a.evaluate(env)` is invalid because `a.evaluate(env)` isn't a reference or pointer. It's a `Expr`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the case where the prototype of `evaluate` is  `fn evaluate(&self, &mut HashMap<String, Expr>) -> Rc<Expr>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a second version where I follow Adrian's suggestion to replace all `ExprNode` with `Rc<ExprNode>`. The only cloned variables are `Rc` pointers, so I guess this just increments a reference count. My only regret is that we lost the method syntax, but I think this can be repaired by defining `Expr` with a `struct` instead of a type alias.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum ExprNode {
    Integer(i32),
    Term(String),
    Plus(Expr, Expr),
    Set(Expr, Expr),
}

type Expr = Rc<ExprNode>;

type Env = HashMap<String, Expr>;

fn evaluate(e: &Expr, env: &mut Env) -> Expr {
    match **e {
        ExprNode::Plus(ref a, ref b) => {
            let a_ev = evaluate(a, env);
            let b_ev = evaluate(b, env);
            match (&*a_ev, &*b_ev) {
                (&ExprNode::Integer(x), &ExprNode::Integer(y)) => Rc::new(ExprNode::Integer(x + y)),
                _ => Rc::new(ExprNode::Plus(a_ev, b_ev)),
            }
        }
        ExprNode::Term(ref a) => env.get(a).unwrap().clone(),
        ExprNode::Set(ref a, ref b) => {
            let b_ev = evaluate(b, env);
            match **a {
                ExprNode::Term(ref x) => {
                    let x_value = env.get_mut(x).unwrap();
                    *x_value = b_ev;
                    x_value.clone()
                }
                _ => Rc::new(ExprNode::Set(evaluate(a, env), b_ev)),
            }
        }
        _ => e.clone(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e = Rc::new(ExprNode::Plus(
        Rc::new(ExprNode::Integer(9)),
        Rc::new(ExprNode::Integer(4)),
    ));
    let mut env = HashMap::new();

    println!("{:?}", evaluate(&e, &mut env));
}
```