# Is it impossible to have a nested match on a recursive datatype that uses a smart pointer like a Box, Rc, or Arc?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to port [this program](https://gist.github.com/jdh30/f3d90a65a7abc7c9faf5c0299b002db3) that computes the `n`th derivative of x^x symbolically to Rust. It seems to be mostly easy:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

type Expr = Rc<Expr2>;

enum Expr2 {
    Int(i32),
    Var(String),
    Add(Expr, Expr),
    Mul(Expr, Expr),
    Pow(Expr, Expr),
    Ln(Expr),
}

use Expr2::*;

fn pown(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    match b {
        0 => 1,
        1 => a,
        n => {
            let b = pown(a, b / 2);
            let b2 = b * b;
            if n % 2 == 0 {
                b2
            } else {
                b2 * a
            }
        }
    }
}

fn add(f: Expr, g: Expr) -> Expr {
    match (f, g) {
        (Int(m), Int(n)) => Int(m + n),
        (Int(0), f) => f,
        (f, Int(n)) => add(Int(n), f),
        (f, Add(Int(n), g)) => add(Int(n), add(f, g)),
        (Add(f, g), h) => add(f, add(g, h)),
        (f, g) => Add(f, g),
    }
}

fn mul(f: Expr, g: Expr) -> Expr {
    match (f, g) {
        (Int(m), Int(n)) => Int(m * n),
        (Int(0), f) => Int(0),
        (Int(1), f) => f,
        (f, Int(n)) => mul(Int(n), f),
        (f, Mul(Int(n), g)) => mul(Int(n), mul(f, g)),
        (Mul(f, g), h) => mul(f, mul(g, h)),
        (f, g) => Mul(f, g),
    }
}

fn pow(f: Expr, g: Expr) -> Expr {
    match (f, g) {
        (Int(m), Int(n)) => Int(pown(m, n)),
        (f, Int(0)) => Int(1),
        (f, Int(1)) => f,
        (Int(0), f) => Int(1),
        (f, g) => Pow(f, g),
    }
}

fn ln(f: Expr) -> Expr {
    match f {
        Int(1) => Int(0),
        f => Ln(f),
    }
}

fn d(x: String, f: Expr) -> Expr {
    match f {
        Int(_) => Int(0),
        Var(y) => if x == y {
            x
        } else {
            y
        },
        Add(f, g) => add(d(x, f), d(x, g)),
        Mul(f, g) => add(mul(f, d(x, g)), mul(g, d(x, f))),
        Pow(f, g) => mul(
            pow(f, g),
            add(mul(mul(g, d(x, f)), pow(f, Int(-1))), mul(ln(f), d(x, g))),
        ),
        Ln(f) => mul(d(x, f), pow(f, Int(-1))),
    }
}

fn count(f: Expr) -> i32 {
    match f {
        Int(_) | Var(_) => 1,
        Add(f, g) | Mul(f, g) | Pow(f, g) => count(f) + count(g),
        Ln(f) => count(f),
    }
}

fn string_of_expr(f: Expr) -> String {
    count(f).to_string();
}

fn nest(n: i32, f: Expr, x: Expr) -> Expr {
    if n == 0 {
        x
    } else {
        nest(n - 1, f, f(x))
    }
}

fn deriv(f: Expr) -> Expr {
    let df = d("x", f);
    format!("D({}) = {}", string_of_expr(f), string_of_expr(df));
    df
}

fn main() {
    let x = "x";
    let f = pow(x, x);
    // FIXME: Read command-line argument
    let df = nest(9, deriv, f);
    format!("{}", count(df));
}
```

The type needs to be converted into a reference counted `enum` in Rust and pattern matching makes for very similar code except... it doesn't work. From what I can gather, patterns in Rust cannot match upon the result of dereferencing an `Rc`. So, no matter what I do, it fails on nested patterns like `(f, Add(Int(n), g))`.

Am I missing something or is it really impossible for nested patterns to match over recursive datatypes in Rust? Apparently there is something called "box syntax" to dereference inside a pattern (amongst other things) that has been on the drawing board for four years.

Comment: *is it really impossible for nested patterns to match over recursive datatypes in Rust?* — no, that's completely possible and standard. *patterns in Rust cannot match upon the result of dereferencing an `Rc`* — you have no dereferencing in this code at all.

Comment: @Shepmaster: "that's completely possible and standard". Great. What am I doing wrong and how do I do it right?

Comment: I copied a bit more than I meant to when quoting. I was going for just *is it really impossible for nested patterns to match*, which is possible and normal. Sorry for any false hope.

Comment: See also [A simple formula interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30004175/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that yes, it is currently impossible to do this. Recursive datatypes require indirection, e.g. `Rc`. Indirection requires dereferences when matching against nested patterns. There is no way to dereference inside a pattern match in Rust today.

The workaround is to compile your patterns by hand, i.e. as if you only had C-style `switch`.

A feature called "box patterns" has been [discussed since 2014](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/469) that may solve this problem in the future but it hasn't shipped.