# Creating recursive enum -- should I use lifetime references? (Rust)

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, algebraic-data-types

I want to create an ADT like:

```rust
pub enum Predicate<'a>{
    And(Box<&'a Predicate>, Box<&'a Predicate>),
    Neg(Box<&'a Predicate>),
    Bool(LogicOp, Literal, Literal)
}
```

But apparently this is not the correct way to specify lifetimes.

My question is two-fold:

1. What's the correct way to define lifetimes here?
2. Is there a better way to tackle this problem?
   I don't want to clone everything each time, because everything is immutable, and because I don't want to create multiple copies. I also want to do stuff like

```rust
let foo = Predicate::Bool(whatever args);
let and = Predicate::And(&foo, &foo);
let neg = Predicate::Neg(&and);
let bar = Predicate::And(&and, &neg);
```

and so forth and continue to be able to use `foo`, `and`, and `neg` later on.

Comment: *But apparently this is not the correct way to specify lifetimes.* - Have you tried something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9f4e2f5474c7488752f453939e65e82f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything really is immutable, then the simplest way to handle this scenario is with `Rc`/`Arc` (the only difference between the two is that the latter can be used for objects accessed from multiple threads.) You can define your enum as follows:

```
pub enum Predicate {
    And(Rc<Predicate>, Rc<Predicate>),
    Neg(Rc<Predicate>),
    Bool(LogicOp, Literal, Literal)
}
```

An `Rc` is a reference-counted shared pointer to a heap-allocated object. You can clone it to obtain a new pointer to the internal data without any copying, and you will never have to worry about lifetimes: internally, the `Rc` keeps track of how many references are being held to its object, and automatically deallocates it when this number drops to zero. This bookkeeping incurs a small runtime cost whenever the `Rc` is cloned or dropped, but greatly simplifies dealing with this sort of shared ownership.

Of course, the use of an `Rc` makes it somewhat more verbose to create predicates. The example you give would become:

```
let foo = Rc::new(Predicate::Bool(whatever args));
let and = Rc::new(Predicate::And(foo.clone(), foo.clone()));
let neg = Rc::new(Predicate::Neg(and.clone()));
let bar = Rc::new(Predicate::And(and.clone(), neg.clone()));
```

(Technically not all these clones are necessary if you did not intend to use, say, `neg` later.)

One way to ease this boilerplate is to use methods or associated functions on the `Predicate` type to create pre-`Rc`ed values, like so:

```
impl Predicate {
    pub fn and(a: &Rc<Predicate>, b: &Rc<Predicate>) -> Rc<Predicate> {
        Rc::new(Predicate::And(a.clone(), b.clone())
    }

    pub fn neg(a: &Rc<Predicate>) -> Rc<Predicate> {
        Rc::new(Predicate::Neg(a.clone()))
    }

    pub fn boolean(op: LogicOp, a: Literal, b: Literal) -> Rc<Predicate> {
        Rc::new(Predicate::Bool(op, a, b))
    }
}
```

With this, your example becomes:

```
let foo = Predicate::boolean(whatever args);
let and = Predicate::and(&foo, &foo);
let neg = Predicate::neg(&and);
let bar = Predicate::and(&and, &neg);
```

There is one unavoidable downside to this approach, though. You cannot `match` through an `Rc` without dereferencing it first, which can make working with `Rc` ADTs somewhat painful. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246510/is-it-impossible-to-have-a-nested-match-on-a-recursive-datatype-that-uses-a-smar) for details.

Comment: Thank you! This seems a bit unwieldy, coming from Haskell... but I guess it can't be helped when you have explicit control over the stack and heap